# Как можно реализовать подобную вещь? (js, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, img

**Как можно реализовать вот такую вещь?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пояснение:** Есть два изображения, которое наложено одно на другое. Необходимо сделать так чтобы при наведении мышкой на блок, частично исчезало изображение на величину зависящую от правого края до мышки.

P.s. я пытался найти в поисковике решение, но не смог сформулировать грамотно запрос.

Comment: Поищите по запросу до\после js. Например https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5+js&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUZ780UZ780&oq=%D0%B4%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5+js&aqs=chrome..69i57.5326j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как то так.

```js
let $black_white = $('.black_white'),
  img_width = $('.black_white img').width(),
  init_split = Math.round(img_width/2);
  
  $black_white.width(init_split);  

 $('.before_after_slider').mousemove((e) => {
  let offX  = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $black_white.offset().left);
  $black_white.width(offX);
 });

 $('.before_after_slider').mouseleave((e) =>{
  $black_white.stop().animate({
  width: init_split
 },1000)
});
```

```css
.before_after_slider {
  position: relative;
  margin: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
.before_after_slider > * {
  position: absolute;
}

.black_white {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="before_after_slider">
  <div class="color">
    <img src="https://indipost-img.s3.amazonaws.com/indipost-img-600x400-747210.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="black_white">
    <img src="https://indipost-img.s3.amazonaws.com/indipost-img-600x400-748565.jpg" width="400" height="300"  alt="black_white" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, а как данная вещь называется?