# Как сделать такой эффект с фотографией? ( Image Comparison Slider )

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Как сделать такой эффект с фотографией, чтобы можно было тянуть за линию влево и вправо? С одной стороны фотография черно белая, а с другой цветная.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/863346/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%89%d1%8c-js-jquery/863364#863364

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Две картинки, одна поверх другой:

```js
(function bubu() {
  var width = 500;
  var height = 250;
  var lineWid = 6;

  var img = {
    right: document.querySelector('.image-right'),
    left: document.querySelector('.image-left')
  };

  setSizes();
  setEventListeners();

  /***/

  function setSizes() {
    img.right.style.width = width + 'px';
    img.right.style.height = height + 'px';
    img.right.style.backgroundSize = width + 'px ' + height + 'px';

    img.left.style.width = width / 2 + 'px';
    img.left.style.height = height + 'px';
    img.left.style.backgroundSize = width + 'px ' + height + 'px';
    
    document.querySelector('.line-separator').style.width = lineWid + 'px';
  }

  function setEventListeners() {
    var line = document.querySelector('.line-separator');
    
    var offsetLeft = img.left.getBoundingClientRect().left;    
    var grabbing = false;

    line.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
      grabbing = true;
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      grabbing = false;
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      if (!grabbing) return;
      
      var linePos = e.pageX - offsetLeft + lineWid/2;
      // e.pageX: Текущая координата мышки
      img.left.style.width = Math.min( Math.max(linePos, lineWid), width ) + "px";
      // Не больше width, не меньше ширины линии
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
.mama {
  position: relative;
}

.image-right, .image-left {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://i.gyazo.com/3d639982375790f7d875454a5850c5e8.png');
}

.image-left {
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: grayscale();
}

.line-separator {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  cursor: grab;
}

.line-separator:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <div class="image-right"></div>
  <div class="image-left">
    <div class="line-separator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: P.s. превратил девушек в котиков... на чистом CSS !))

Answer (score 8):

Что-то коллеги тут перестарались со скриптами. Вот две строчки на CSS :))

```css
.image {display: inline-block; position: relative; line-height: 0;}

.image>div {position: absolute; overflow: hidden; box-sizing: border-box; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 10%; max-width: 100%; border-right: 2px solid; resize: horizontal; filter: grayscale(1);}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div><img src="https://24.kz/media/k2/items/cache/d73bdd80d92870b5f02033844c11a7d5_Generic.jpg" /></div>
  <img src="https://24.kz/media/k2/items/cache/d73bdd80d92870b5f02033844c11a7d5_Generic.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: каждый день узнаешь что-то новое, +1, никогда такого не видел)

Comment: Цитата из вопроса «...чтобы можно было тянуть за линию влево и вправо...» поэтому перестарались) Пользователь легко может не додуматься, что кликать надо где-то внизу. Хотя идея прикольная)

Comment: @Sevastopol' АХахах здорово! )))

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить div сверху и указать у него режим ЧБ и по движению бегунка менять его ширину

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .imgContainer{
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-size: cover; 
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        let isTaken = false; // была ли нажата кнопка мыши
        let img = 'https://hackeru.pro/uploads/Banner/110/image/01_1985ef16f2.png';
        let body = document.body;

        // создание самой картинки
        imgElem = document.createElement('div');
        imgElem.classList.add('imgContainer')
        imgElem.style.position = 'relative';
        imgElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+img+"')";
        body.appendChild(imgElem);

        // создание ЧБ экрана
        let screen = document.createElement('div');
        screen.style.position = 'absolute';
        screen.style.width = '50%';
        screen.style.height = '100%';
        screen.style.left = '0';
        screen.style.top = '0';
        screen.style.backdropFilter = 'grayscale(100%)';
        imgElem.appendChild(screen);

        //создание линии
        let line = document.createElement('div');
        line.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        line.style.position = 'absolute';

        line.style.width = '3px';
        line.style.height = '100%';
        line.style.left = '50%';
        line.style.top = '0';
        line.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        line.style.zIndex = 10;
        imgElem.appendChild(line);

        // включение режима передвижения ширмы
        imgElem.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
            isTaken = true;
        })
        // выключение режима передвижения ширмы
        imgElem.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){ 
            isTaken = false;
        })

        //обработка движения мышью
        imgElem.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
            if (!isTaken) return //проверка включенности режима пережвижения ширмы

            line.style.left = event.screenX + 'px';
            screen.style.width = event.screenX + 'px'

            // в случае, если мы зашли за пределы экрана режим выключается
            if (line.offsetLeft >  imgElem.offsetWidth - line.offsetWidth/2){
                isTaken = false;
                line.style.left = screen.offsetWidth- line.offsetWidth/2 + 'px';
            }
        })


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас что-то пошло не так) При любом тыке всё становится серым.

Comment: я затрудняюсь ответить на ваш комментарий) если "тык" произвести по картинке и потянуть курсор, то проблем возникать не должно)

Я проверяю на Chrome у меня все ок

Comment: @Sevastopol' прошу вас следовать видеоинструкции, это должно помочь вам сделать "тык" и воспроизвести желаемый результат )

https://clck.ru/MiaGW